# setting RPATH for python not working

Tags: python, elf

I tried changing the RPATH of python using patchelf to point to the new updated libraries installed locally. But python is still unable to find the new libraries.

On the contrary, if i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, then python works fine.

I am doing the following
`patchelf --set-rpath /home/user/new_lblas/ /home/user/.local/python`

where the `new_lblas` points to updated packages like intel-lapack, blas etc.

If i now do, `python -c 'import numpy'`,  it complains `libblas.so.3gf` not found.
However if i set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/new_lblas`, then `import numpy` in python works fine.

can someone help figure out what mistake i am doing?

The output from `readelf -d /home/user/.local/python` after doing patchelf is given below

```
     Dynamic section at offset 0x270 contains 26 entries:
     Tag        Type                         Name/Value
    0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/user/new_lblas]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libutil.so.1]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x41b700
    0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x569238
    0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x4146b0
    0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x3ff460
    0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x4085c0
    0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              37214 (bytes)
    0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
    0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
    0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x7f9fe8
    0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           8040 (bytes)
```

Before doing patchelf, the ELF header looks as shown below

```
    Dynamic section at offset 0x1f9e00 contains 25 entries:                                           
      Tag        Type                         Name/Value                                              
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]                        
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]                             
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libutil.so.1]                           
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]                             
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]                              
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]                              
     0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x41b700                                                 
     0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x569238                                                 
     0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x400298                                                 
     0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x40f6a8                                                 
     0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x4035b8                                                 
     0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              36637 (bytes)                                            
     0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)                                               
     0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0                                                      
     0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x7f9fe8                                                 
     0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           8040 (bytes)                                             
     0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
```

Comment: Please format your question so it's readable.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Sorry about the bad formatting. Hope its better now

Comment: Your question still lacks all relevant details. Is the `readelf -d` before or after you've run `patchelf` on it? What is the value of `$newpath`? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks for your patience. I have updated the question with all the details you had requested. I know patchelf is not working, as when i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable with same path used for patchelf python numpy starts working.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 3 ways to set the dynamic linker search path:

1. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/new_lblas`
2. Rewrite the binary to set `DT_RPATH` dynamic tag with the value `/home/user/new_lblas`
3. Rewrite the binary to set `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic tag with the value `/home/user/new_lblas`.

The #1 and #2 above are equivalent, but #3 (which is what you are doing) is not. The difference is subtle: `RPATH` affects the binary *and* all shared libraries, but `RUNPATH` affects *only* the binary, and *does not* recursively apply to shared libraries that this binary loads.

That explains why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works, but `RUNPATH` doesn't.

Looking at patchelf [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/patchelf.1.html), it appears that you want:

```
--force-rpath
          Forces the use of the obsolete DT_RPATH in the file instead of
          DT_RUNPATH. By default DT_RPATH is converted to DT_RUNPATH.
```

Comment: using --force-rpath did not do anything. However if i used --add-needed, then  it starts working

Comment: Just for reference – *The ld dynamic linker does not search DT_RUNPATH locations for transitive dependencies, unlike DT_RPATH.* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)